# WSO2 EI : to add pipe delimiter in csv file

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am working in one of the use case where the mapping to be done from csv to csv. Using WSO2 EI 6.3.0
I have requirement to add pipe delimiters in to the output file. The input file I am getting from database which has pipe delimiter but when the message is going through the data mapper it does not get mapped to the final output and adds ',' on its own.
Is there a way to achieve pipe delimiters in the message in wso2 ei.

Can someone please help....
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the OS you're running and how things are configured, there may be Regional Settings that are overriding the default delimiter.  For instance, on Windows 10, hit Start -> type Region and Language setting -> Click Additional Date, Time, & Regional Settings -> Click Change Date, Time, and Number Formats -> Additional Settings... -> and then find the List Separator value, change it to a pipe, restart your runtime, and then test.

Comment: I didnot get your response.
However, I have been able to achieve this using smooks in proxy configuration.